# Apache rewrite causes server error 403 when genuine directory exists after extension removal rewrite

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I've spent a couple of days now trying to create a specific rule set that will allow me to remove `.html` extensions from all the files in the directory and present neater URIs. I'm using a `.htaccess` file in the root directory of that website and the plan is to use this across a number of sites that will have the same issues.

I've been through many iterations of similar config but the closest I have found is actually stripped directly from a post on here (which I sadly wasn't able to comment on to find out more). So the below is what I currently have:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.html -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.html [L]

ErrorDocument 404 https://example.com/404
```

It's simple and works really well for the most part, but when a genuine directory exists then it seems to throw a 403 server error.

For example, if I visited `example.com/directory_A` - I get a 403 error. However, there is actually a file in the root directory with the same name so I expect it to actually present `example.com/directory_A.html` (but without the `html` of course). In the `directory_A` directory there is a file, `file_B.html`, and visiting `example.com/directory_A/file_B` presents the `file_B.html` content as expected.

I'm going round in circles with this - this is definitely the closest I have come to solving my problem but I just don't know enough to get me over this last hurdle so any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but when a genuine directory exists then it seems to throw a 403 server error.

The 403 is not caused by the rule you posted. The first *condition* specifically excludes directories anyway, so it isn't even processed.

The 403 is caused by mod_dir trying to serve a `DirectoryIndex` document (eg. `index.html`) from the `/directory_A/` subdirectory - which presumably does not exist.

Specifically, when you request `/directory_A` (without a trailing slash) mod_dir will "fix" the URL by appending a trailing slash via a 301 (permanent) redirect. Then, on the redirected request, mod_dir tries to serve the directory index from that directory and triggers a 403 if it does not exist and directory listings are disabled (mod_autoindex).

To do as you require you need to prevent mod_dir from appending the trailing slash on physical directories with the `DirectorySlash Off` directive. Then, in order to serve `/directory_A.html` (instead of *passing through* the `/directory_A` request) you need to remove the first *condition* that excludes requests for directories.

For example:

```
# Ensure that directory listings are disabled
Options -Indexes

# Prevent mod_dir appending a slash to physical directories
DirectorySlash Off

# Rewrite request to append ".html" extension if it exists
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.html [L]
```

Note that directory listings *must* be disabled if you are setting `DirectorySlash Off` otherwise mod_autoindex will generate a directory listing when requesting a directory without a trailing slash and the corresponding `.html` file does not exist. Note the security warning in the Apache docs regarding the [`DirectorySlash` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash).

In the `RewriteCond` directive I changed the use of `REQUEST_URI` to use the backreference from the `RewriteRule` *pattern* instead to be consistent - to ensure you always use the same value in both the `RewriteCond` *TestString* and the `RewriteRule` *substitution*.

Note that requesting `/directory_A/` (with a trailing slash) will still result in a 403 response, but this is expected unless you specifically want to handle this edge case and route requests to `/directory_A.html` instead? **UPDATE:** This is best achieved by implementing an external redirect to simply remove the trailing slash from the URL when a corresponding `.html` file exists, so the rewrite (above) then does its thing and appends the `.html` extension on the redirect response. This ensures you have a single canonical URL, avoiding a potential *duplicate content* issue (where `/directory_A` and `/directory_A/` both return the same resource).

For example, add the following "redirect" rule immediately *before* the above "rewrite" rule:

```
# Remove trailing slash on URL-path when the corresponding ".html" file exists
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f
RewriteRule (.*)/$ /$1 [R=302,L]
```

This doesn't explicitly check for the directory, so it will also work on other "files" as well. eg. `/directory_A/file_B/` will be redirected to `/directory_A/file_B` (trailing slash removed).

Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect and only change to a 301 (permanent) redirect when you are sure it's working as intended in order to avoid potential caching issues.

You will need to make sure the browser cache is cleared before testing, since the earlier 301 that mod_dir triggered to append the trailing slash on the directory will have been cached by the browser.

<sub>TBH, it is better to avoid such conflicts to begin with and not have files with the same basename as physical directories when implementing "extensionless" URLs.</sub>

---

*Aside:*

#### Optimisation

Your directive that appends the `.html` extension could be optimised, since it is currently testing *every* request for the existence of a file with `.html` on the end (which is relatively expensive and probably unnecessary). eg. request `/images/myimage.jpg` and your rule will check for the existence of `/images/myimage.jpg.html` on the filesystem. You could avoid these unnecessary checks by excluding requests that already include a file extension (assuming your URLs don't intentionally have dots near the end of the URL-path that looks like a file-extension).

For example:

```
# Rewrite request to append ".html" extension if it exists
RewriteCond $1 !\.\w{2,4}$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.html [L]
```

#### ErrorDocument

> ```
> ErrorDocument 404 https://example.com/404
> ```

This directive is arguably incorrect.

1. When you specify an absolute URL it will trigger a 302 (temporary) redirect for the error document, not an internal subrequest as it should be. Consequently the client does not see the 404 HTTP status unless you manually set this in the redirect response. But either way, the client sees a 302 first.
2. You should specify the actual URL of the 404 error document here, not the "extensionless" version (which requires additional processing to happen), as you appear to be doing here. This is entirely internal to you server, the client does not see this URL.

For example:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

Although it's often preferable to have your error documents in a separate subdirectory that is trivial to exclude from other redirects/rewrites. eg. `/errordocs/404.html`.

Comment: Thank you, this has been most helpful. Unfortunately, these problems are symptomatic of the software we use to export websites built with the tool so it's really difficult to avoid some of these conflicts and issues. When you ask whether I want to handle the edge case and still supply a page when going to /directoryA/ - I would indeed - is it possible to do this dynamically so all directories would utilise the same rule or would this have to be hardcoded per directory?

Comment: Also, regarding the error documents, I completely agree - again, the error files are exported in the same root location and is on my list of things to sort. Because I don't have full control over the paths to the assets, and relative URLs are in use, I plan to use exactly your example and have JQuery rewrite the relative URLs on the error page to use the style sheets in the root dir as currently these don't look pretty when the page thinks the location is in a directory.

Comment: @iratefox "still supply a page when going to `/directoryA/`" - Yes, you can do this dynamically for _all_ directories in the same way we are rewriting to append the `.html` extension. However, it is better to do this with an external redirect to "canonicalise" the URL. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Perfect. Just perfect. Thank you very much for your support.